# What, other the .row() can cause a libgdx table to start a new row?

Tags: libgdx

Bit of a mystery to me this, but I have a table in libgdx where everything is being positioned in new cells vertically;

[image: image of cells appearing vertically with debug on]

I am not using .row() anywhere. 
Probably doing something stupid here but I cant see it.
Clues as to what can cause this?

(I'll post the code if needed, but its not that neat, and seeing as I think knowing *anything* that can cause a newline will help me, it shouldn't necessarily be needed)

*edit*
Tried to cut the code down to all the bits that happen when an item gets added

### Code;

//function that triggers on adding

//SSSNode is a semantic reference for the items details,it just justs made into a label like object

```
public void addItem(SSSNode itemsnode){

    Item newitem = new Item(itemsnode); //Item extends label    
    allItems.add(newitem);

    super.add(newitem).size(60, 30).top().left().fillY().expandY();

    //pack();
    //super.invalidate();       
    //super.validate();  (tried doing pack, validate, and none...neither helped)

    //update the GUI bar in case the inventory tab isnt there yet
    MainExplorationView.usersGUI.setDataVisible(true);


}
```

The following code is in "usersGUI", which creates and handles the popup called inventory which is whats in the picture and is the table I cant get to behave.

```
//ensures the interface for the inventory popup is setup and visible
//also refreshes the links 
public void setDataVisible(boolean visible){

    if (myContents.isVisible!=true){
        myContents.isVisible=visible;

        refreshlinks();
        setupInventory(); 
    }
}

private void refreshlinks() {
    super.clearChildren();
    super.addActor(backgroundobject);
    super.addActor(ME.playersInventory); //re adds the inventory panel table?

    int y = 440; 
    ME.playersInventory.validate(); //revalidated the table (I dumped this almost everywhere in frustration)
    //below is not relevant, it updates other items in a onscreen gui
    for (InterfaceButton link : allLinks) {     

        if (link.isVisible==true){

            link.setPosition(5,y);  
            super.addActor(link);
            y=y-30;
        }

    }

    backgroundobject.setSize(85, 200);
    backgroundobject.setPosition(0,y+20);           



}
//ensures inventory is setup once.
public void setupInventory() {

    if (setup){         
        return;     
    } 
    Log.info("setupInventory");


    ME.playersInventory.setPrefWidth(super.getWidth());

    Log.info("width is "+super.getWidth());

    ME.playersInventory.setHeight(200);


    ME.playersInventory.pack();

    float X = myContents.getX();
    float Y = myContents.getY()-ME.playersInventory.getHeight();

    Log.info("popping up inventory at:"+X+","+Y);
    ME.playersInventory.setPosition(X, Y);


    super.validate();
    setup=true;
}
```

The full code is also on GitHub;
https://github.com/ThomasWrobel/MeshExplorerGDX
The whole project is a game being made to demo/test and open source distributed semantic database system. The relevant bit is the inventory and the maybe the gui that creates it.

Anyone with good knowledge of LibGDXs workings should I think not need to look any of the code though if theres other things that can tell a table to start a new row. (ie, any layout restrictions that can cause it to happen automatically? )

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: I did so, but its horrible code as it stands.

Comment: Did you try to use just the add() method of the table instead of the addActor() method ? I tried with addActor() and nothing came up. Usin add I manged to refresh a test table without any issues.

Comment: I used addActor to add the inventory table to its parent as I wanted it positioned absolutely, if this was html Id think of it as "hovering" over the rest of the page.
I can try add....but surely how the table itself is added to its parent shouldn't affect how things are added within the table? (which as you can see I have just used add(...) for)

Comment: Calling .pack() causes the item to layout and so do .validate() (that causes all children to .validate() too). Maybe, as you're calling it in a table and after adding a new item to a table cell, it calls the .row() method or equivalent in that cell. I don't understand why you're calling so much .pack() and .invalidate() and .validate() on that GUI ;)

Comment: Mainly out of desperation due to this problem. ;)
I tried removing the pack and keeping the validate, no difference. Tried the other way around no difference.
Also, updated the code so refreshlinks() and setupInventory() only fire the first time an item is added. So I dont think its got anything to do with them either

Comment: However, I have spotted one difference; It DOES go in a row if the inventory is closed when the data is added. The inventory being closed just means I set ME.playersInventory.setVisible(false);
Why should visibility make a difference?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout` ending the current row was a side effect to make the layout logic simpler. It is now [fixed](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/b1483bf4589424f661f4cbca1b08420cce5f6a0d).

Note HorizontalGroup is still a better fit for your use case and has the benefit that you can add/remove actors at any index.

Comment: Thanks, Id since used HorizontalGroup, but its still nice to have this cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that layout() causes new rows;
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15857&p=68533&hilit=layout#p68533

Adherently this is how its supposed to work, despite the docs not saying that.